# Why am I getting bad references to AxWMPLib?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, axwindowsmediaplayer

I've got a couple of classes that use the AxWMPLib.MediaPlayer control, and I've just migrated all of my classes into a single library ( from a couple of windows forms projects ).

The problem I am having is that even after exposing references to the MediaPlayer COM Object, I am still getting 'missing assembly' errors for this namespace.

I wonder if there is anything that must be specifically done in a 'Class Library' project to include these references, or if I am just totally overlooking something obvious...

Suggestions for my seeming incompetence would be much appreciated...

Comment: Are you using a library which uses another library? You may have to have your main project reference the 3rd library too.

Comment: My 'Main' project uses my library, which is then supposed to reference  AxWMPLib - yes, but the above mentioned error is occurring in My library, not in the 'Main' project.

Answer (score 0):

Imported the DLLs directly from my original project ( which had been copied to the output directory in my original build ).